# Creating Scenario Text boxes in Rise of Nations

Tags: rise-of-nations

How do you create a text box when the scenario begins to play? I want to set parameters for the person playing but so far I haven't figured it out. Additionally, is it possible to place multiple text boxes in the middle of the scenario at different times?

Comment: If you're making a scenario or mod, I believe that belongs on GameDev.

Comment: I posted this question there 2 months ago and it was voted down to -9 saying it belongs here.

Comment: Is the map/scenario editor in-game, or is it a standalone program?  Only if it's in-game do we allow them, as that is part of gaming, then.  If it's a standalone program, then it's not.

Comment: @YoungGuilo then it should have been migrated

Comment: THis is in-game and not a stand alone program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply displaying text to the user at the start of the scenario can be done by with the `popup_dialog` function, and putting it in the `run_once` section of a script in the scenario.

It sounds like you want to get user feedback. The only solution I know is to use a `popup_choice` function. These functions display a message, and two (or three) buttons for the user to click on. The function returns the number of the option the player selected. You can use the return value for whatever you need.

Two button version

```
int popup_choice( string message_text, string message_accept, string message_reject);
```

And three button version

```
int popup_choice( string message_text, string message_one, string message_two, string message_three);
```

And here's how it looks running the scenario

[image]

Comment: Lol, took forever but thanks for the answer.